# Sony wf-1000xm3 audio quality is different between Mac and Android for the same song

Tags: macos, ios, mac, android

Today I was listening to "Lil jon - Get low Bass Boosted HQ HD" on YouTube using my Sony wf-1000xm3 earbuds. First I was using my Mac (16-inch, 2019) to stream the song and then I used my mobile (OnePlus 6). In my mobile, I had the "Sony | Headphones Connect" app installed as well.

On my mobile, the audio quality was fantastic and I could feel the base properly. But, when I used my Mac it was totally out. Audio quality in Mac felt like that I was using some cheap headset. (BTW, Mac's inbuilt speakers had better sound quality)

Any ideas?

Comment: What App did you use on your Mac?  I personally don't use iTunes (or Apple Music now) except for the Library functionality.  Take a look at [Colibri](https://colibri-lossless.com/) as it sounds much, much better.

Comment: Actually, I played the song on YouTube and it was opened in Google Chrome

Comment: Great question, I actually have the same question. Between Spotify on Android and Spotify on Mac, there is just no comparison, the sound is deep and clear on Android, crappy and flat on Mac. :(